# Sylius empty payment method choices

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I started a Sylius project, but when I have to choose a payment method, there is no choice available.

[image: payment method frontend]

However, I have added several payment methods in the backend.

[image: payment method backend]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check other 2 places:

1.) If you got your payment method enabled/choosen for your channel (under channels settings)

2.) if you dont have products in delivery groups that dont allow some payments (under product)